# At which point does the pressure of the water act on a dam?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

I'm currently working on a problem. I have a dam with height h, and width w. As part of the problem I need the torque resulting from pressing against the dam. I calculated the amount of force applied as follows:

$$
p(z) = \rho \cdot g \cdot z \\
dF = \rho(z)\cdot dA = \rho gwz \cdot dz \\
F = \int_0^h\rho gw z \cdot dz = \frac 12 \rho gwh^2 
$$

For the torque, I need the lever arm, for which I need to know where this force acts on the wall, but I'm kind of stuck there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
This is the situation I'm dealing with:
[image]
The water is on the left and I need the torque in regard to axis B.

Comment: about what point are you trying to compute the torque?  The base of the dam?

Comment: I edited the post, take a look at the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure force is distributed across the whole dam wall. To find the torque about the bottom of the wall you need to integrate $z \space dF$ from $z=0$ to $z=h$.

Answer (score 0):

$d \tau$=$F$×$r$

=$\rho g (h-y)(dy)$×y

On integrating and putting limits from 0 to h

$\tau$= $\rho$g$h^3/6$    I.e h/6 from bottom

### Extra

For calculating effective distance use torque

$d \tau$=$F$×$r$

=$\rho g y(dy)$×y

$\int \tau$ =$\int$$\rho g y^2(dy)$

$\tau$=$\rho$g$h^3/3$

---

This shows the effective distance is h/3 from point of application i.e from top